# scipy interpolating a 2D array

Tags: numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a 2D array, shape = (490,1000), as input. My goal is to linear interpolate this array.
My code:

```
x_row= np.arange(0,490)
x_row_long=[]
y_column= np.arange(0,1000)
y_column_long=[]

#x-coordinates
for i in range(1000):
    x_row_long= np.append(x_row_long, x_row, axis=None)  

#y coordinates
for i in range(490):
    y_column_long= np.append(y_column_long, y_column, axis=None)  

#values from array
values_1d= np.ravel(2D_array)

#interpolate
scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x=x_row_long, y=y_column_long, z=values_1d, kind='linear', copy=True, bounds_error=False, fill_value=None)
```

The output is an error with the message: **Too many data points to interpolate**.

Comment: `values_1d= np.ravel(2D_array)` where is this 2D_array coming from? Can you provide a smaller version of the whole problem first? That way others can reproduce what you are trying to do and then try to understand why the error is occurring when scaled up.

Comment: You should use [numpy.mgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) and [RegularGridInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html) if your data is on a grid. Otherwise, use [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) or [RBFInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator.html).